# Assigning unique IDs to strings

Tags: python, pandas, database

I am trying to build an elegant solution to assigning IDs starting from 0 for the following data:

My Attempt at first creating IDs for the 'Person' category is like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Person': ['Tom Jones','Bill Smeegle','Silvia Geerea'],
    'PersonFriends': [['Bill Smeegle','Silvia Geerea'],['Tom Jones'],['Han Solo']]})

df['PersonID'] = (df['Person']).astype('category').cat.codes
```

which produces
[image]

Now I want to follow the same process but do this for the 'PersonFriends' column to get this result below. How can I apply the same functions to achieve this when I have a list of friends?

[image]

I have been able to do this via the `hash()` function on each name, but the ID generated is long and not very readable. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you combine the names from both columns so you can use the same IDs in each?

Comment: yes...good idea. Then I could somehow map that back to the PersonFriends column?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to come up with the specific mechanics for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dict and apply values from key

```
id_map = dict(zip(df["Person"], df["PersonID"]))
df["FriendsID"] = df["PersonFriends"].apply(lambda x: [id_map.get(y) for y in x])
```